# why the following not automatically create the reference object

Tags: java, spring

Using Spring

```
<bean id="id2" class="class2">
</bean>

<bean id="id1" class="class1">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="id2" />
</bean>
```

if using getbean("id1"), I found that id2 is not automatically created. How to force id2 created before id1 is created?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by id2 is not automatically created - do you see null passed as the first argument to class1's constructor?

Comment: In this example, `id2` *will* be automatically created. If this is a stripped down sample, you've omitted something important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should work.  Spring figures out what the dependencies are from the wirings, and creates things in the required order.

If it does not, check that the class names are correct, that the `class1` and `class2` have appropriate constructors, and other things that might prevent instantiation of the two beans.  Also, check that you haven't specified something with a constructor argument dependency cycle; e.g.

```
<bean id="id2" class="class2">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="id1" /> </bean>

<bean id="id1" class="class1">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="id2" /> </bean>
```

If this answer doesn't help, please provide us with the FULL stacktrace, and the relevant excerpts from the  REAL wiring files.

---

My reading of the [Spring 3.0 documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-dependson) is that a `depends-on` attribute *should not* be necessary for the OP's example.  The `ref` should be sufficient to tell the Spring that there is a dependency, and cause it to instantiate the beans in the right order.

Comment: +1 for the better answer, though we don't know what version of Spring is being used.

Comment: it turns out that class2 get created, something else prevent me to see the correct result first. Thanks Stephen.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by explicitly specifying that bean "id1" depends on "id2" by:

```
<bean id="id2" class="class2">
</bean>

<bean id="id1" class="class1" depends-on="id2">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="id2" />
</bean>
```

Comment: This should make no difference. There's already an explicit dependency from `id1` to `id2`, there's no need to add an another one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also work with inner beans, if bean id2 is only used as the constructor-arg for id1.

```
  <bean id="id1" class="class1">
      <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="class2">
        </bean>
      </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

(Edited typo)